# How do I conduct a comparison of two 6x4 frequency tables that hold different data?

Tags: frequency

I am trying to statistically compare two frequency tables (6x4) of two independent samples (see picture for example of one group's table).

[image]

What would be the best way to evaluate whether these frequencies are different?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated. If this is a homework, assignment, or other self-learning question, please add the `[self-study]` tag and [read its wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: The frequencies in the table are certainly different. 79 $\neq$ 0, for example -- that's not really a statistical question, which generally relates to some form on inference about unobserved/unobservable things like population quantities. Are you interested in making some inference about comparing population proportions in rows or in columns? How does this question arise?

Comment: The table in the picture represents the frequencies for only one group ("1976 research"). There is an additional table ("2016 research") that holds data which are still being collected from another sample. So, I am interested in comparing all of these rows and columns to the rows and columns in an identically structured table with different contents (the frequencies will presumably not be identical, but I want to test their statistical difference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could fit a log-linear model. You would include terms to fix the various sample margins so you would include age, category, year. You would probably want to include other terms as well depending on your exact scientific hypothesis so if the age structure differs by year but you regard that as a nuisance you would include age * year and so on. When you have thus arrived at your null model which fixes all the aspects of the structure you can then test further interactions corresponding to your scientific hypothesis.